# PHP Audio Volume

Tags: php

Upon loading my website up you're greeted with a large selection of music from the directory "audio", this audio is set to loop and select a new song with each new session/refresh.

The one issue I'm facing at the moment with my php is lowering the volume of the audio as it is extremely loud.

How would I go about lowering the volume of the songs?

This is my PHP

```
<?php
    //Select Random Songs & Play the Audio
$dir = "audio/";
$song = scandir($dir);
$i = rand(2, sizeof($song)-1);

echo "<audio class='audio' autoplay autobuffer='autobuffer' loop='infinite'>";
echo "<source type='audio/mp3' src='audio/" . $song[$i] . "'>";
echo "</audio>"


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the volume property:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.volume = 0.2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`<audio>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) exposes the audio volume as an attribute, so you can add that to your output:

```
echo '<audio volume="0.5" ...></audio>';
```